# R shiny retrieve tables from same output function & show in ui side by side

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a cumbersome function inside a server output variable.
The function returns a list of 2 data frames. 
I want to extract these tables and plot them side by side. 
However I do not want to create two different outputs for them in server, as I don't want the heavy function to run twice.

For the sake of giving a reproducible code : 
(my getListOfDataFrames function is much heavier than in this example)
I want df1 and df2 displayed side by side with scrollX = TRUE in options

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("output1")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  getListOfDataFrames <- function(df){
  return(list(df[1:5,], df[6:10,]))   
  }

  output$output1 <- renderDataTable({

    myList <- getListOfDataFrames(mtcars)

    df1 <- as.data.frame(myList[1])
    df2 <- as.data.frame(myList[2])

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: One option is to save each one of your data frames, say with write.csv, and then load them reactively as output1 and output2. You might need to throw an action button and an observeEvent()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of examples how to create dynamic content, like example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("dt")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  getListOfDataFrames <- function(df){
    return(list(df[1:5,], df[6:10,]))   
  }

  myList <- getListOfDataFrames(mtcars)

  output$dt <- renderUI({
    ntables <- seq(myList)

    # we want to create the width depending how many tables we have
    width <- paste0(99/max(ntables),"%;")

    lapply(ntables, function(i) {
      id <- paste0("dt", i)
      div(style=paste0("display:inline-block;width:",width),DT::dataTableOutput(id))
    })
  })

  observe({
    # Dynamically creating 2 tables with separate ids
    lapply(seq(myList), function(i){
      id <- paste0("dt", i)
      output[[id]] <- DT::renderDataTable(as.data.frame(myList[i]))
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: hey @Pork Chop thanks a lot this helps.
But 2 things. One, I will always have a list of only 2 tables. And secondly, my tables in the output are overlapping :/

Comment: Hi Pork Chop never mind for displaying them side by side. I'm merging them one under the other for better comparison. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686235/r-rbind-while-preserving-order-or-rows-in-each-data-frame#54686429